# User-defined literal operator (constexpr constructor)

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang

I'm implementing a class that defines a complex number with the possible arithmetics that goes with it. Now, I am trying to write a user-defined literal operator:

```
constexpr Complex operator "" _i(long double arg) {
    return Complex{0.0, arg};
}
```

This lets me write the following:

```
Complex c = 1.0 + 5.0_i;
```

For this, I have to implement a constexpr constructor that goes with it:

```
constexpr Complex(double real, double imaginary) : re(real), im(imaginary) {};
```

where *re* and *im* are the member variables. This works fine when compiling in **g++** but as soon as I'm using **clang** I get this error:

```
error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression[-Winvalid-constexpr]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is g++ less restrictive than clang?

The whole implementation below:

```
class Complex {
 private:
   double re;
   double im;
 public:
   // Class constructors
   Complex() : re(0.0), im(0.0) {};                      
   Complex(const double real) : re(real) {};
   constexpr Complex(const double real, const double imaginary) : re(real), im(imaginary) {};

/* All the overloaded functions etc. below */

};

constexpr Complex
operator "" _i(long double arg) {
  return Complex{0.0, arg};
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your exact error, but I was able to get [an error regarding the conversion from `long double` to `double`](https://godbolt.org/g/k9nQEg)

Comment: Why not all your constructor are `constexpr` ?

Comment: Is operator double + Complex constexpr?

Comment: Narrowing conversion are ill-formed within a constant expression, although the code you provided does not produce the error you show your operator is ill-formed since `Complex{0.0, arg}` narrows from long double to double.